# How to make this complicated query faster [MySQL]?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have the next query:

```
SELECT JL.j_id, COUNT(*) as total
FROM j_log JL
WHERE JL.log_time > '20120205164008'
AND JL.j_id IN (
     SELECT j_id 
     FROM j 
     WHERE checked = '1' 
     AND expires >= '20120207164008'
) GROUP BY JL.j_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3
```

j table has big structure 100 fields and 248986 rows inside it.

next KEY's are present in it

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`j_id`),
  KEY `expires` (`expires`),
  KEY `checked` (`checked`),
  KEY `checked_2` (`checked`,`expires`)
```

j_log table has about 63000000 records and the next structure

```
CREATE TABLE `j_log` (
  `j_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `log_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `j_id` (`j_id`),
  KEY `log_time` (`log_time`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

so the considered query wants to get top3 of most visited j_id instances

this is the plan

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type            | possible_keys                     | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | JL    | index           | log_time                          | j_id    | 4       | NULL | 63914602 |     0.36 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | j     | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,expires,checked,checked_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | func |        1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Some times it could take up for 15!!! minutes.

Is there any way how to make faster ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JL.j_id, COUNT(*) as total
FROM j_log JL
INNER JOIN j
  ON JL.j_id = j.j_id
  AND j.checked = '1'
  AND j.expires >= '20120207164008'
WHERE JL.log_time > '20120205164008'
GROUP BY JL.j_id
ORDER BY total
DESC LIMIT 3
```

Will this be faster?

Comment: Your `inner join` will only pickup 1 row, so total will be 1 for all of them.

Comment: not true. there are as many records per j_id as there are records in the j_log table with that id that meets the datetime constraint.

Comment: ah sorry, I changed the order of the tables in my example, but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

- Why do you use a subquery?
- Why is `checked` a string? ('1' instead of just 1)
- Why do you compare `jl.log_time` and `j.expires` diffrently (`>` vs `>=`)

How about this query

```
     SELECT j.j_id, COUNT(jl.j_id) as total
       FROM j
  LEFT JOIN j_log jl ON (jl.j_id = j.j_id AND jl.checked = '1' AND jl.log_time > '20120205164008')
      WHERE j.expires >= '20120207164008'

   GROUP BY j.j_id 
   ORDER BY total DESC 
      LIMIT 3
```

Make sure `j_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for both tables and put an index on j.expires and jl.checked and jl.logtime.
Also make sure the field `checked` is optimized. I'm not sure what the possible values can be, but I assume it's a boolean field. So rather make the field_type `BIT` or use an `ENUM`

**Edit**

Also you should convert the fields `j.expires` and `jl.log_time` to better fields. I think it is just a `varchar` now, looking at the current value you use: 20120205164008. Convert this into a `DATETIME` field (but don't just convert the tables because you will lose the data).

Comment: You cannot make `j_id` a PRIMARY KEY in `j_log` table because there are obviously many rows with the same `j_id` there, otherwise why would OP need to count them?

Comment: 1. I did not. this query was written before me, now i'm investigating whole logic. so there is no any answer yet :)
2. good question. but can it make slower whole query ?
3. because value is different :) i'm thinking so

Comment: piotrm: you're right, I was not paying attention. j_log.j_id should be an index. user1016265: for question 2; yes it is quite important to improve the speed. Check what the fieldtype is for that field... 63m records is not that much that the query should take long..

Comment: actually i found that even original query takes 1.2 sec but sometimes when visitors coming  it makes all other queries in LOCKED state .. why ?

Comment: "To achieve a very high lock speed, MySQL uses table locking (instead of page, row, or column locking) for all storage engines except InnoDB, BDB, and NDBCLUSTER." - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html
You are probably using MyISAM as DB engine.. 1.2 seconds for a query is very long though. What machine are you running on? And do you need to run this query all the time? p.s. have you read my 'edit' above?

Comment: yes j table actually still MyISAM, will convert it at evening.
Machine spec: CPU http://ark.intel.com/compare/33081,47922 left one is ours, 16Gb RAM. Yes this query should run every 10 minutes.

Comment: you should rather try to improve your query, than converting the engine without further research... Converting to InnoDB is not going to solve the speed issue..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7417/discussion-between-user1016265-and-richard)